# Setting a Scheduled Automation to Active with REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, automationstudio

I can activate scheduled automations through soap but only if their schedule is not already configured. Does anyone know how to activate a scheduled automation through REST API? I think the "isActive" value should do it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can not activate an automation using REST API for now. I have tested a lot of payloads and endpoints without sucess and I believe it is not possible..

Comment: That is unfortunate, thanks for the info!

Comment: yeah i think you can only activate it by recreating the schedule via SOAP and pushing it in a Schedule request.